# How to map one entity to several DB tables with Fluent Nhibernate automapping conventions

Tags: nhibernate, fluent, automapping, convention

I have one entity `CustomProperty` in domain model which is used from several other entities.

```
Product
{
    int Id;
    Collection<CustomProperty> CustomProperties;
}
```

and

```
Order
{
    int Id;
    Collection<CustomProperty> CustomProperties;
}
```

But in DB, I do not want just one table `CustomProperty` which contains nullable foreign key to `Product` table and another nullable foreign key to `Order`. Instead, I need two separate tables `ProductCustomProperty` and `OrderCustomProperty`.

I need to do that with automapping and conventions. Does anyone have any ideas?

Btw, I have had an idea which does not work for me. Maybe anyone have the clue why:

```
   public class CustomPropertyConvention : IHasManyConvention, IHasManyConventionAcceptance
   {
         public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
         {
                instance.Table("ProductCustomProperty");
         }

         public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IOneToManyCollectionInspector> criteria)
         {
                criteria.Expect(i => i.Relationship.Class.Name == "CustomProperty" && i.Relationship.EntityType == typeof(Product));
         }
   }
```

This example must have worked perfectly, but IOneToManyCollectionInstance.Table() does not set anything.

Answer (score 0):

`one-to-many` relationships ignore the table, because the FK column goes in the many-side entity.

To put it another way, you can't have a single CustomProperty entity mapped to two different tables (it doesn't make sense).

You can either use a `many-to-many` mapping, or map CustomProperty as a composite type instead of entity.